# How to completely destroy arrayPool

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

```
    var arrayPool = ArrayPool<byte>.Create(80 * 1024, 100);
    List<byte[]> list = new List<byte[]>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        list.Add(arrayPool.Rent(1024 * 1024));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        arrayPool.Return(list[i], true);
    }
    arrayPool = null;
    GC.Collect(0);

    //arrayPool.Shrink(); or arrayPool.Clear();
```

In general, other pool libraries have automatic crop pool sizes. What if I allocate a large amount of memory in a short period of time?

Comment: Reading [the code](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/ConfigurableArrayPool.cs), it looks like `ArrayPool` allocates up to the limits your specify, and then stays at those limits. If you want to completely throw away the `ArrayPool` though, just destroy all references and let the GC clean it up

Comment: If your `arrayPool` variable is nulled out, then GC will clear it when necessary, when there is memory pressure. Why do you *need* to trigger GC if there is no memory pressure?

Comment: arrayPool = null；

Memory is not recycled.

Comment: Well, yes of course the memory from the arrays are not freed when doing `arrayPool = null; GC.Collect(0);`. Because for one, who says the arrays are still gen-0? And secondly -- and more importantly here -- the arrays are still hold by your List<byte[]> instance...